# PHP array_search - right way to get values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a big CATEGORIES array with structure

```
[0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 1028 
[name] => Sale woman 
[slug] => sale-woman 
[term_group] => 0 
[term_taxonomy_id] => 1028)

[1] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 1029 
[name] => Sale man 
[slug] => sale-man 
[term_group] => 0 
[term_taxonomy_id] => 1029)...
```

I don't need so many values, i show only part of this array(). So, i create my own array from this array

```
$ids = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ( $cats as $key=>$cat ) {

$ids[$i]['id'] = $cat->term_id;
$ids[$i]['catname'] = $cat->name;
$i++;

}
```

It works well and returns me

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1028 [catname] => Sale woman ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 1029 [catname] => Sale man ) )...
```

Than i need to find current category in this array and get next and prev ids of categories. I try

```
$thisindex = array_search( $this_category_id, $ids['id'] );

$previd = $ids[ $thisindex - 1 ];

$nextid = $ids[ $thisindex + 1 ];
```

But when i try to ECHO $previd or $nextid it returns nothing. `$this_category_id` works well, i think problem is in `array_search( $this_category_id, $ids['id'] );`

I try also $ids[]['id'] - cause an error

$ids[$i]['id'] - nothing returns

How to find `$previd` and `$nextid`? Need help

Comment: you will get the index of `$ids['id']`  You need an array of IDs

Comment: I dont see what yuo have actually achieved by converting the original array into your `$ids` array Other than turning a perfectly usable array of Objects into an array of arrays and wasting a block of time and memory in the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $array = array_column($ids, 'id'); //array of ID 
 $thisindex = array_search( $this_category_id, $array );
```

Or build one yourself in the foreach

```
$ids = array();
$array = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ( $cats as $key=>$cat ) {

    $ids[$i]['id'] = $cat->term_id;
    $ids[$i]['catname'] = $cat->name;
    $array[$i] = $cat->term_id;
    $i++;

}
```

Or you can write your own search function.

Your array looks like this

```
 [ 
    0 => [ 'id' => 1, ..],
    1 => [ 'id' => 2, ..],
 ]
```

But your search is like this

```
['id' => [....]]
```

Well except there is no `id` in the top array, just `0`,`1` etc.  And even if there was, `id` is not of the type of array, but instead probably and Int.

***UPDATE***

To make the array loop, you have to check if you are before the start and after the end like this:

```
$previd = $ids[ $thisindex - 1 ];
$nextid = $ids[ $thisindex + 1 ];
$min = 0;
$max = count( $ids ) - 1;

if( $previd < $min ) $previd = $max;
if( $nextid > $max ) $nextid = $min;
```

if its less then 0 then it equals the count of the array - 1 ( the end ), if it's past the end then it equals the start or ( 0 ) in this case.

Comment: Yeap!!! It works...oNE more question - when element $thisindex is first, it doesn't shows $previd. Is it possible to show last element?

Comment: yes,  `if( $previd < 0 ){  end( $array); $previd = key( $array );}`  Or you can use `end($id)` and just return the last item.  or `count( $id ) - 1`  you will have same issue with next at the end of the array